# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k} \geq \frac{7}{12}$

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, harmonic-numbers

For all integers $n\geq2$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k} \geq \frac{7}{12}$$

How would you prove this by induction?

Comment: $\frac 1 {n+1+k} < \frac 1 {n+k} $. Do you know by how much. Can you prove $\sum (\frac 1 {n+1+k} - \frac 1 {n+k} + \frac 1 {2 (n+1)} \le 0$?

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k} = H_{2n}-H_{n}$$
are the terms of an increasing sequence, since
$$ H_{2n+2}-H_{n+1}-H_{2n}+H_n = \frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}>0.$$

Comment: I don't see how this helps though?

Comment: @Ivy: $\sum_{k=1}^{2}\frac{1}{2+k}=\frac{7}{12}$ and I have just proved the next terms are bigger.

Answer (score 0):

By induction you can do:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{n+1+k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k} -\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}=\\
=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}+\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\ge \frac{7}{12}+\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\ge \frac{7}{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

If
$s_n
= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
s_{n+1}
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{n+1+k}\\
&= \sum_{k=2}^{n+2}\dfrac{1}{n+k}\\
&= \sum_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{1}{n+k}+\dfrac1{2n+1}+\dfrac1{2n+2}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{n+k}-\dfrac1{n+1}+\dfrac1{2n+1}+\dfrac1{2n+2}\\
&= s_n+\dfrac{(2n+1)+(2n+2)-2(2n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\
&= s_n+\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$s_{n+1} > s_n$,
so $s_n$
is increasing.

Therefore,
if $n > m$,
$s_n > s_m$.

Note that
we can bound $s_n$ because

$\begin{array}\\
s_{n+1}
&= s_n+\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\
&< s_n+\dfrac{1}{(2n)(2n+2)}\\
&< s_n+\frac14\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}\\
&< s_n+\frac14(\dfrac1{n}-\dfrac1{n+1})\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$s_{n+1}-s_n
< \frac14(\dfrac1{n}-\dfrac1{n+1})
$.

Summing,
$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(s_{n+k+1}-s_{n+k})
< \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac14(\dfrac1{n}-\dfrac1{n+1})
$
or
$s_{n+m}-s_n
\lt \frac14(\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+m})
\lt \frac1{4n}
$.

Therefore,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$
exists,
and,
if
$S=\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n$,
$S < s_n +\dfrac1{4n}$.

We can similarly get a
lower bound on $s_n$
and, therefore,
a lower bound on $S$
in terms of $n$ and $s_n$.

(the following is done
with copy, paste, and edit.)

$\begin{array}\\
s_{n+1}
&= s_n+\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\
&> s_n+\dfrac{1}{(2n+2)(2n+4)}\\
&> s_n+\frac14\dfrac{1}{(n+2)(n+2)}\\
&> s_n+\frac14(\dfrac1{n+1}-\dfrac1{n+2})\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$s_{n+1}-s_n
\gt \frac14(\dfrac1{n+1}-\dfrac1{n+2})
$.

Summing,
$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(s_{n+k+1}-s_{n+k})
\gt \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac14(\dfrac1{n+1}-\dfrac1{n+2})
$
or
$s_{n+m}-s_n
\gt \frac14(\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+m+1})
$
so that
$S
=\lim_{m \to \infty}s_{n+m}
\ge s_n+\lim_{m \to \infty}\frac14(\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{n+m+1})
= s_n+\frac1{4n+4}
$.

Therefore
$S \ge s_n +\dfrac1{4n+4}$.

Therefore,
for any $n$,
$s_n +\dfrac1{4n+4}
\le S 
< s_n +\dfrac1{4n}$.